# How can I make the slideshow stop? And what ways can I improve the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slideshow that (for testing purposes) swipes through every 1 second. I have it to stop when it gets back to the first image. But when it stops on it and I click on the next button nothing happens. And when I do mess with it it will start swiping through again.

I've tried while statements but that's really it.

My code:

```js
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var time = 1000;

images[0] = 'michael-baird-14942-unsplash.jpg';
images[1] = 'kees-streefkerk-352781-unsplash.jpg';
images[2] = 'hakon-sataoen-1484216-unsplash.jpg';
images[3] = 'mario-silva-1492028-unsplash.jpg';
images[4] = 'will-turner-1474611-unsplash.jpg';

function changeImg() {
  document.slide.src = images[i];

  if (i < images.length) {
    i++;
  } else if (i > 4) {
    document.slide.src = images[0];
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }

  if (i == 0) {
    $('.next').on('click', function() {
      i++;
    });
  }

  setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}
window.onload = changeImg;
```

```css
.slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
}

.slideshow img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <img name="slide" alt="Slideshow Images" width="100%" height="100%">
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="masterjs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

As you can see in the JavaScript it goes through and stops at the first image. But as you can also see that this isn't a very good way to do this. If you guys can can you try to keep it in JavaScript/jQuery? If not or there is a better way please post it. But basically because of the way that it is it cycles through stops at the beginning and stays but if you mess with it VIA the next button it causes it to restart. I basically want it to cycle through the images and then stop at the beginning allowing the user to then cycle through them themselves. Also I want to add animations between images that's why I am asking for other ways that may be better for that too.

Comment: `i++` itself does nothing but increase `i`, you should also update `src`.

Comment: and please ask one question at a time, `add animations between images` is another question.

Comment: Idk how to update ```src``` with the next button. I want it to be able to change the images with the next button without it restarting because of the if statement it causes it to restart

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer Below javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 0;
  var firstSlide = 0;
  var images = [];
  var time = 1000;
  images[0] = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SiVr9DM_EG0/maxresdefault.jpg';
  images[1] = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d4/Mickey_Mouse.png';
  images[2] = 'https://files.brightside.me/files/news/part_41/419860/18057510-1549810-23-0-1513767199-1513767212-650-1-1513767212-650-ce9f862cd3-1513864405.jpg';
  images[3] = 'http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/999/mcs/media/images/80286000/png/_80286528_penisvagina.png';
  images[4] = 'https://d345cba086ha3o.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Chota-Bheem-Aur-Krishna-Drawing-e1451484119715.jpg';

  function changeImg() {
    if (i <= images.length && firstSlide == 0) {
      document.slide.src = images[i];
      if (i < images.length) {
        i++;
      } else if (i > 4) {
        document.slide.src = images[0];
      } else {
        i = 0;
      }
      setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
    }
  }

  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    firstSlide = 1;
    i++;
    var ind = (i % 5);
    document.slide.src = images[ind];
  });

  $('.prev').on('click', function() {
    firstSlide = 1;
    i--;
    var ind = (i % 5);
    document.slide.src = images[ind];
  });
  window.onload = changeImg;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the way that I wanted it and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this condition:

```
else if (i > 4) {
    document.slide.src = images[0];
  }
```

Your image updates to the first element of the `images` array, and your counter stops incrementing. Try mentally running through your code while keeping track of the value of `i`. Once this condition is met, does it ever stop being met?

The solution is simple, just reset the value of `i` when you reset the image:

```
else if (i > 4) {
    document.slide.src = images[0];
    i = 0;
  }
```

You may then run into issues with your event listener as it triggers when `i == 0`, and therefore will be triggered when `i` is reset as above. There are some good reasons to use `i === 0` instead, I recommend looking into it!

In addition, you should consider using a `array.push()` to add to the `images` array.

Finally I'd also recommend using `console.log()` as a way to keep track of what your code is actually doing -- this should aid in the debugging process.